# Why does gcc want me to link to libgcc_ext.10.5.dylib?

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I've built GCC 4.9.2 on Mac OS X from source statically (using --disable-shared), for C language only (not C++), with the static version of libgcc (libgcc.a). Of course, since I only built the static version of libgcc, there's no such thing as libgcc*.dylib. GCC has built and installed libgcc.a (as expected) and that's all fine. Now when I invoke this newly-built copy of GCC using the following command (using a simple hello, world! example):

```
gcc -v test.c -o test
```

it shows these compiler flags as default:

```
-no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem
```

No, no no! I don't want you to try to link to a shared version of libgcc! Don't you remember I told you that at the configuration step? And if I use the -static-libgcc option, I get this:

```
-no_compact_unwind -lgcc_eh -lgcc -lSystem
```

libgcc_eh? HUH? When was that built during GCC compilation? Oh right, it wasn't, hence why it can't find libgcc_eh.a.

What's going on here? I specifically told GCC I didn't want shared libraries, so why is it trying to link to them by default? I can, of course, remedy all this by using -nodefaultlibs and specifying -lgcc and -lSystem manually, but why should I have to do that?

Furthermore, the GCC documentation has this to say:

*-shared-libgcc
-static-libgcc
On systems that provide libgcc as a shared library, these options force the use of either the shared or static version, respectively. If no shared version of libgcc was built when the compiler was configured, these options have no effect.*

So, based on this, I take it that if I did not specifically ask GCC to build a shared version of libgcc, it should not assume I would want to link to anything but a static version. But, for some reason, it does anyway. I haven't been able to find a configure option that would prevent this, nor an option that lets me specify which "default libs" get linked to by default. It seems GCC is forcing me to link to a shared version of libgcc that isn't there unless I suppress this using -nodefaultlibs. This seems backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to fix this. I had to edit /gcc/config/darwin.h in GCC's source and comment out where the macro REAL_LIBGCC_SPEC is defined. By leaving this macro undefined, it ensures GCC will only pass the -lgcc and -lSystem library flags during linking, which is what I wanted.

The GCC docs for the compilation driver explain what this and other macros do:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Driver.html

*— Macro: LIBGCC_SPEC
Another C string constant that tells the GCC driver program how and when to place a reference to libgcc.a into the linker command line. This constant is placed both before and after the value of LIB_SPEC.
If this macro is not defined, the GCC driver provides a default that passes the string -lgcc to the linker.*

*— Macro: REAL_LIBGCC_SPEC
By default, if ENABLE_SHARED_LIBGCC is defined, the LIBGCC_SPEC is not directly used by the driver program but is instead modified to refer to different versions of libgcc.a depending on the values of the command line flags -static, -shared, -static-libgcc, and -shared-libgcc. On targets where these modifications are inappropriate, define REAL_LIBGCC_SPEC instead. REAL_LIBGCC_SPEC tells the driver how to place a reference to libgcc on the link command line, but, unlike LIBGCC_SPEC, it is used unmodified.*